# Why not all data from FirebaseDatabase reference is getting added in an ArrayList<String>?

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving some data from a particular `FirebaseDatabase` reference and trying to add it in an `ArrayList<String>` but something strange is happening as they aren't getting added one after another.

somewhere in `onCreate()`:

```
pA = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here's my code:

```
aRef.child(reID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) childSnapshot.getValue();
                if (pA != null){ 
                  pA.clear();
                }
                pA.add(map.get("pA"));
                Log.d("pA", String.valueOf(pA));
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "no data available yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here's data structure:

```
-app
  -child
    -reID
      -uniqueID1
        -userID1
          -key: value
          -key: value
          -pA: value1
      -uniqueID2
        -userID2
          -key: value
          -key: value
          -pA: value2
      -uniqueID3
        -userID3
          -key: value
          -key: value
          -pA: value3
```

Here's what getting logged out:

```
D/pA: [value1]
D/pA: [value2]
D/pA: [value3]
```

I tried removing `if (pA != null) {pA.clear();}`, but then I got this log:

```
D/pA: [value1, value1, value2, value1, value2, value3]
```

**What I want** is this:

```
D/pA: [value1, value2, value3]
```

Please let me know what's going wrong here and how can I achieve above given result?

Comment: Where is array list in your code? And what is pA?

Comment: @MrunalAhirrao `pA` is the arraylist. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @cricket_007 please help with this issue

Comment: Have you tried moving `if (pA != null){pA.clear();}` before (out of) the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

The way a value listener work in firebase, especially the way you are using it, if a child is added to a node you are listening to, you once again receive all the children. This is why you get value1, value1, value2, value1, value2, value3 if you don't clear the arraylist. First value1 is added, then when value2 has added to firebase your listener receives an object with both.

> This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing all data at that location, including child data.
>   [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

**Solution**

The easiest way for you to fix this without changing to much code is by clearing pA outside of the for loop. That way you will get all of the currently exisiting 'pA':s each time the event fires.

```
if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
        if (pA != null){ 
            pA.clear();
        }
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
 .
 .
 .
```